# sql pulling a row for next or previous row of a current row

Tags: sql, mysql

```
id    |  photo title     |  created_date

XEi43 |  my family       |  2009 08 04
dDls  |  friends group   |  2009 08 05
32kJ  |  beautiful place |  2009 08 06
EOIk  |  working late    |  2009 08 07
```

Say I have the id `32kJ`.  How would I get the next row or the previous one?

Comment: The concept of "next" or "previous" depends on the order. 

You probably  might do this programatically, by retriving a DataSet using ado.net or other technology, and then looping through the records of that representation of the data.

Comment: It is easily doable if your id field was sequential and numeric, the fact that you're using alphabetical characters makes it a lot trickier.

http://www.scottklarr.com/topic/111/how-to-select-previousnext-rows-in-mysql/

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This is what I use for finding previous/next records.  Any column in your table can be used as the sort column, and no joins or nasty hacks are required:

Next record (date greater than current record):

```
SELECT id, title, MIN(created) AS created_date
FROM photo
WHERE created >
  (SELECT created FROM photo WHERE id = '32kJ')
GROUP BY created
ORDER BY created ASC
LIMIT 1;
```

Previous record (date less than current record):

```
SELECT id, title, MAX(created) AS created_date
FROM photo
WHERE created <
  (SELECT created FROM photo WHERE id = '32kJ')
GROUP BY created
ORDER BY created DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

Example:

```
CREATE TABLE `photo` (
    `id` VARCHAR(5) NOT NULL,
    `title` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    `created` DATETIME NOT NULL,
    INDEX `created` (`created` ASC),
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
ENGINE = InnoDB;

INSERT INTO `photo` (`id`, `title`, `created`) VALUES ('XEi43', 'my family',       '2009-08-04');
INSERT INTO `photo` (`id`, `title`, `created`) VALUES ('dDls',  'friends group',   '2009-08-05');
INSERT INTO `photo` (`id`, `title`, `created`) VALUES ('32kJ',  'beautiful place', '2009-08-06');
INSERT INTO `photo` (`id`, `title`, `created`) VALUES ('EOIk',  'working late',    '2009-08-07');

SELECT * FROM photo ORDER BY created;
+-------+-----------------+---------------------+
| id    | title           | created             |
+-------+-----------------+---------------------+
| XEi43 | my family       | 2009-08-04 00:00:00 |
| dDls  | friends group   | 2009-08-05 00:00:00 |
| 32kJ  | beautiful place | 2009-08-06 00:00:00 |
| EOIk  | working late    | 2009-08-07 00:00:00 |
+-------+-----------------+---------------------+


SELECT id, title, MIN(created) AS next_date
FROM photo
WHERE created >
  (SELECT created FROM photo WHERE id = '32kJ')
GROUP BY created
ORDER BY created ASC
LIMIT 1;

+------+--------------+---------------------+
| id   | title        | next_date           |
+------+--------------+---------------------+
| EOIk | working late | 2009-08-07 00:00:00 |
+------+--------------+---------------------+

SELECT id, title, MAX(created) AS prev_date
FROM photo
WHERE created <
  (SELECT created FROM photo WHERE id = '32kJ')
GROUP BY created
ORDER BY created DESC
LIMIT 1;

+------+---------------+---------------------+
| id   | title         | prev_date           |
+------+---------------+---------------------+
| dDls | friends group | 2009-08-05 00:00:00 |
+------+---------------+---------------------+
```

Comment: i havent tried it, but im sure this will pull the result, i just wonder, which one if more fast query.

Comment: Why do you use aggregated  functions if you already have ordered the results and limited it to 1 row?

Answer (score 2):

I realize that you are using MySQL, but just for reference, here is how you would do this using Oracle's analytic functions LEAD and LAG:

```
select empno, ename, job,
  lag(ename, 1) over (order by ename) as the_guy_above_me,
  lead(ename, 2) over (order by ename) as the_guy_two_rows_below_me
from emp
order by ename
```

I guess there's a reason why Oracle costs money and MySQL is free... :-)

This page shows you [how to emulate analytic functions in MySQL](http://onlamp.com/pub/a/mysql/2007/04/12/emulating-analytic-aka-ranking-functions-with-mysql.html?page=2).

Comment: You get these analytic functions in Postgres 8.4 as well :p

Answer (score 2):

Did you want the next/previous row by date?  If so, you could do this:

```
select MyTable.*
from MyTable
join
  (select id
   from MyTable
   where created_date < (select created_date from MyTable where id = '32kJ')
   order by created_date desc, id desc
   limit 1
  ) LimitedTable on LimitedTable.id = MyTable.fund_id;
```

Comment: jeremy stein, can you also please tell me, if i can check postion of current row from total rows (showing 6 of 100 rows), can this query do it or would i need to extend the query, if extend, then how or what do i have to do? i just want to also know the position of current row from total rows, so i can make it work with next and previous.. so users know where they at, like on facebook.

Comment: i want to add positioning too for current row, other then next and previous.. how can i do that? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2036425/little-complex-sql-row-postion

Comment: Yes, you could do those things, but it probably would make more sense to do it from the calling application.

Answer (score 1):

Using ***Mike's*** MAX/MIN trick we can make previous\next jumps for all sorts of things.  This msAccess example will return the previous close for every record in a stock market data table.  Note: the '<=' is for weekends and holidays.

```
SELECT 
   tableName.Date,
   tableName.Close,
   (SELECT Close 
      FROM tableName 
      WHERE Date = (SELECT MAX(Date) FROM tableName 
                     WHERE Date <= iJoined.yesterday)
   ) AS previousClose
FROM 
 (SELECT Date, DateAdd("d",-1, Date) AS yesterday FROM tableName)
  AS iJoined 
INNER JOIN 
    tableName ON tableName.Date=iJoined.Date;
```

...'yesterday' demonstrates using a function(*Date-1*) jump; we could have simply used...

```
(SELECT Date FROM tableName) AS iJoined
  /* previous record */
(SELECT MAX(Date) FROM tableName WHERE Date < iJoined.Date)
  /* next record */
(SELECT MIN(Date) FROM tableName WHERE Date > iJoined.Date)
```

The trick is we can previous\next # of *whatever(s)* with MAX\MIN and a jump function()

Answer (score 0):

Horrible hack - I don't like this but might work..

```
with yourresult as
(
select id, photo_title, created_date, ROW_NUMBER() over(order by created_date) as 'RowNum' from your_table
)
-- Previous
select * from yourresult where RowNum = ((select RowNum from yourresult where id = '32kJ') -1)
-- Next
select * from yourresult where RowNum = ((select RowNum from yourresult where id = '32kJ') +1)
```

That of any use?

Comment: probably not, unfortunatly. It's MS SQL - I had a quik think yesterday lunch but didn't have much time - I'll have another look tonight..

Comment: im getting this error #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'with yourresult as
(
select photo_id, title, added_date, ROW_NUMBER() over(ord' at line 1

Answer (score 0):

I considered id as primary key in the table (and as "row number"), and used it to compare each record with the record before.
The following code must work.

```
CREATE SCHEMA temp
create table temp.emp (id integer,name varchar(50), salary  varchar(50));
insert into temp.emp values(1,'a','25000');
insert into temp.emp values(2,'b','30000');
insert into temp.emp values(3,'c','35000');
insert into temp.emp values(4,'d','40000');
insert into temp.emp values(5,'e','45000');
insert into temp.emp values(6,'f','20000');

select * from temp.emp

SELECT
    current.id, current.name, current.salary,
    case 
        when current.id = 1 then current.salary 
        else 
            case
                when current.salary > previous.salary then previous.salary
                else current.salary  
            end
     end
FROM
    temp.emp AS current
    LEFT OUTER JOIN temp.emp AS previous
    ON current.id = previous.id + 1
```

Comment: Do you need solution to compare prev and next record in single query.so try above ..