# MySQL Next / Previous Alphabetical Row

Tags: mysql

It's possible that this is really easy and it's just Friday brain problems but I'm struggling here...

I have a MySQL table which contains text entries such as :

```
Elephant
Apple
Dog
Carrot
Banana
```

I pull one row, ie Dog. I now want to pull the previous alphabetical row and the following alphabetical row, ie Carrot & Elephant

So..

```
SELECT text FROM table WHERE text >= 'Dog' ORDER BY text LIMIT 1
```

Gives me the next alphabetical row. However,

```
SELECT text FROM table WHERE text <= 'Dog' ORDER BY text LIMIT 1
```

perhaps obviously gives me the first alphabetical row of the table. I figured I could get table position and then order alpahbetically and do a LIMIT x-1,1 to get previous but that seems awful clunky.

I'm sure I'm missing something obvious but my head hurts.

Ideas ?

Comment: wouldn't it be easier to read the whole table into something like a linked list and then get the next and previous item to the one your afer?

Comment: Have a look at my answer to a previous similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1259458/sql-pulling-a-row-for-next-or-previous-row-of-a-current-row/2827609#2827609

Answer (score 3):

`ORDER BY text DESC`

Answer (score 0):

Here is the cleanest and most efficient way:
To get next:

```
 select min(name) people where name > 'Dog';
```

To get previous:

```
 select max(name) people where name < 'Dog';
```