# Get previous / next record in sqlite

Tags: sql, sqlite

Currently my query looks like this:

```
SELECT name FROM items
  WHERE something = "foo"
AND name > (SELECT name FROM items WHERE name = ?)
GROUP BY name
ORDER BY name ASC
LIMIT 1
```

(found it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1259458/sql-pulling-a-row-for-next-or-previous-row-of-a-current-row))

It seems to work, but if I change `>` to `<` (to get previous record), I get no results, even though I know there are :(

What am I doing wrong?

`name` is a TEXT field, but I'd like to be able to sort by any other field, so I want my query to work with any type.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get the previous row in this way, you will have order the names in descendinng order instead of ascending, otherwise you will always get the first name.  Also: In this case it is better to use `select distinct` instead of `group by`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT name FROM items
WHERE something = 'foo'
AND name < (SELECT name FROM items WHERE name = ...)
ORDER BY name DESC
LIMIT 1
```

This works on sqlfiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/a9f68/3/0

Answer (score 1):

Trying using strcmp() as detailed at http://www.sqlite.org/datatypes.html

I think one issue for you might be that your `>` is not working as you suspect in the first instance.