# How get next row and previous row for now row in table

Tags: mysql, sql

[**STRUCTURE TABLES AND ERROR WHEN EXECUTE QUERY ON SQLFIDDLE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a926a/1)

I have table `News`.

For example i get row where `NewsIdn = '164955'`:

```
SELECT * FROM News WHERE NewsIdn = '164955'
```

Previous row have `NewsIdn = '270085'` and next row have `NewsIdn = '324955'`.

Tell me please how get previous `NewsIdn` and next `NewsIdn` with help mysql query?

Comment: Do you mean something like this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1259458/sql-pulling-a-row-for-next-or-previous-row-of-a-current-row

Comment: @user2183923 thanks, I have not seen it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe something like this:

### Main query:

```
SELECT * FROM News WHERE NewsIdn = '164955';
```

### Previous row:

```
select * from News WHERE ID < 
    (select ID from News where NewsIdn = '164955') Order by ID DESC Limit 1;
```

### Next row:

```
select * from News WHERE ID > 
    (select ID from News where NewsIdn = '164955') Order by ID Limit 1;
```

Comment: Why do you need the sub query?

Comment: Cant really guarantee the order of the select list will be the same each time ... select the ID less than the original one will always get the 'correct' row.

Comment: I just realized that NewsIdn is not the ID of the row. Your answer would be indeed correct.

Comment: @learner -- yes -- i now see.  I added a DESC to the query for previous.  Now works.  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a926a/13

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Previous:

```
SELECT * FROM News WHERE NewsIdn < '164955' ORDER BY NewsIdn DESC LIMIT 1
```

Next:

```
SELECT * FROM News WHERE NewsIdn > '164955' ORDER BY NewsIdn LIMIT 1
```